# Yaml Parsing from a config file

Tags: java, parsing, yaml, classcastexception

This is the first time i am using a YAML parser and I am currently stuck at this point

I have a config file which goes something like

```
Users
 -Name:A
  Id : x
  Addr:10.0.0.1
 -Name:B
  Id  :y
  Addr:10.0.0.2

HomeAddress
 City:bla bla
 Country:bla bla

Office Address
 City:abchd
 Country:bha bha ba
```

So I thought the best way to parse it would be to have a list like this.

```
List<Map<String, obj>> Object = (List<Map<String, obj>>) yaml.load(input);
```

Objective was to access the object by specifying a string. Like Username A, I shld be able to obtain his id and IPAddr (This is the most important to me at the moment). But when I tried this declaration, I got an error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at Message.MessagePasser.<init>(MessagePasser.java:34)
```

Can someone please help me debug this. I am running by a deadline!!:(

Answer (score 3):

The YAML parser seems to be returning a `Map`. So you should use it like this:

```
Map config = (Map) yaml.load(input);
Map usersConfig = config.get("Users");
```

Also what particular YAML parser are you using?

**Update 1:** If you look at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Loading_YAML), the `load` method either returns a `List` or `Map` depending on the contents of your YAML file. As your YAML file starts with a key-value mapping (`Users`) and not an array (`-`), the `load` method returns a `Map` which is the appropriate type to be returned in this case.

Comment: I am using a SnakeYaml Parser

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Taking your tip on this one, I modified my code to something like `Map<String,nodeIP> obj = (Map<String,nodeIP>) yaml.load(input);` But inspite of this, I have an error which says it cannot cast java.util.ArrayList to NodeIP type (which is a class defined by me). So Can you suggest some change on this?

Comment: @ExceptionHandler Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/collections/TypeSafeMap2Test.java) test case (especially `testLoadMap`) and its accompanying YAML [file](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/resources/examples/map-bean-12.yaml) to see how that would work. In short, SnakeYaml needs some extra information regarding how a JavaBeans maps to a YAML element and back.

Comment: Your Update1 is a fantastic tidbit.  I just spent an hour trying to work out why code that worked before stopped working ... it's because I ignorantely put a thingo: into my YAML, changing the return value type of the load!!

Answer (score 1):

1) check the validity of your YAML here: http://instantyaml.appspot.com/

2) Your document should look like this: (mind the spaces !)

```
Users : 
 - Name : A
   Id : x
   Addr : 10.0.0.1
 - Name : B
   Id   : y
   Addr : 10.0.0.2
```

Comment: Your validator does not work anymore, here is another one : http://www.yamllint.com/ . Also, the good formatting seems to remove spaces between keywords and ':' and '-' should be on a empty line, with the attributes coming on CR LF.